# Arrays C# Error Unity3D

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors, unityscript

i m trying to convert this code from Js to c# but i m having some trouble. The code is about creating a gride with Arrays. Here is the script , works fine in Unityscript :

```
var levelArray : int[,]; var levelSize : Vector2 = new Vector2(19,13);

var steelblock : Transform;

function Start ()
{
  SetupLevel();
}

function SetupLevel()
{
  levelSize.x = Mathf.FloorToInt( levelSize.x );
  levelSize.y = Mathf.FloorToInt( levelSize.y );

  levelArray = new int[ levelSize.x, levelSize.y];

  var block : Transform;

  for( var y : int = 0; y < levelSize.y ; y++)
  {
    for(var x : int = 0 ; x < levelSize.x ; x++)
    {
      if(x == 0 || x == levelSize.x - 1 ||y ==0 || y == levelSize.y -1)
      {
        levelArray[ x , y ] = 2;
        block = Instantiate(steelblock,Vector3(x,y,0), Quaternion.identity);
        block.name = "steel_"+x.ToString() + "_"+ y.ToString();
        block.parent = transform;
      }
      else if(x% 2 == 0 && y %2 ==0)    
      {
        levelArray[ x , y ] = 2;
        block = Instantiate(steelblock,Vector3(x,y,0), Quaternion.identity);
        block.name = "steel_"+x.ToString() + "_"+ y.ToString();
        block.parent = transform;
      }    
    }
  }
}
```

tried to convert this code from Javascript to C#, but I'm having some errors.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
  int[,] levelArray ;

  Vector2 levelSize = new Vector2(19,13);

  Transform steelblock;
  // Use this for initialization
  void Start () 
  {
    SetupLevel ();
  }

  void SetupLevel()
  {
    levelSize.x = Mathf.FloorToInt( levelSize.x );
    levelSize.y = Mathf.FloorToInt( levelSize.y );

    levelArray = new int[ levelSize.x, levelSize.y];

    Transform block ;

    for( int y  = 0; y < levelSize.y ; y++)
    {
      for(int x = 0 ; x < levelSize.x ; x++)
      {
        if(x == 0 || x == levelSize.x - 1 ||y ==0 || y == levelSize.y -1)
        {
          levelArray[ x , y ] = 2;
          block =  Instantiate(steelblock,new Vector3(x,y,0), Quaternion.identity);
          block.name = "steel_"+x.ToString() + "_"+ y.ToString();
          block.parent = transform;
        }
        else if(x% 2 == 0 && y %2 ==0)    
        {
          levelArray[ x , y ] = 2;
          block =  Instantiate(steelblock,new Vector3(x,y,0), Quaternion.identity);
          block.name = "steel_"+x.ToString() + "_"+ y.ToString();
          block.parent = transform;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The errors are in this line:

```
levelArray = new int[ levelSize.x, levelSize.y];
```

It tells me "Cannot implicitly convert type float' to int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)" and i have another error in this line:

```
block = Instantiate(steelblock,new Vector3(x,y,0), Quaternion.identity);
```

It tells me " Cannot implicitly convert type UnityEngine.Object' to UnityEngine.Transform'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)" in my c# script.

Can you help please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The compiler error message really tells you what is wrong: levelSize's type is `Vector2`. The properties `X` and `Y` are of type `float`, not `int`. The other issue is of a similar type: the compiler cannot cast the different `UnityEngine` types hence you need to do this yourself.

Change the specific code lines to something like this. It's not the nicest way to do and haven't tested it, but it may work:

```
levelArray = new int[Convert.ToInt32(levelSize.x), Convert.ToInt32(levelSize.y)];
```

and

```
block =  Instantiate(steelblock as UnityEngine.Transform, new Vector3(x,y,0), Quaternion.identity);
```